# Gráfico Dinâmico usando Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

sou novato no Xamarin, sei que devem existir componentes prontos para o que necessito, já procurei, mas ainda não encontrei.
Preciso criar um gráfico assim:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update

Eu usava isto no PhoneGap (html5 + JS), agora que estou migrando para xamarin forms, gostaria de saber se algum componente de terceiros faz o que necessito ou se vou precisar fazer tudo do zero.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Melhor controle é  OxyPlot, testei e ele é capaz de fazer o que necessito. (http://oxyplot.org/), é bem superior a todos, inclusive os pagos !
Pode ser instalado via Nuget (https://www.nuget.org/packages/OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms/2015.1.889-alpha)

Comment: Tentei configurar o Xlabs e o OxyPlot sem sucesso no meu projeto Xamarin Forms. Você está fazendo em Xaml?

Answer (score 1):

Tem vários (não sei se atente sua necessidade), aqui estão alguns que encontrei:

[OxyPlot - Gratuito](https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/OxyPlotDemo/Screenshots/pieseries.png) Site oficial: [Documentação](http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms.html)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Xlabs - Gratuito](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/Charting)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Syncfusion - Pago* (Salvo engano tem versão community)](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/xamarin/chart)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Telerik - Pago](http://www.telerik.com/xamarin-ui/chart)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu baixei e testei estes, são muito simples, não atendem, mas talvez com programação eu consiga o mesmo resultado. Mas antes de escrever código, gostaria de tentar encontrar algo pronto